# built in webcam is not shown

Tags: windows-xp, webcam

Hi I am using compaq cq40 144tu notebook.
i installed xp on it.
i cant see any webcam in it.
I reinstalled xp in my system,but there is no change in it.
previously it done well,but now i am not getting any webcam in it.
there is no imaging devices in device manager.
How can i get my builtin webcam back.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it might be a Chipset Problem. If it's only a clean XP Installation you might install various drivers:
i found a listing here:
http://laptop-driver.blogspot.com/2009/02/compaq-cq40-144tu-xp-drivers.html
(i have not checked the contents, use at your own risk)

install HD Sound aswell, i remember having trouble with other components on one of my systems without that driver, or just install drivers for every part of your system.